# Extract a range of elements with a gap in between

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to extract the "te band" values from this list:

```
"tefreqs:", "k index", "k1", "k2", "k3", "kmag/2pi", "te band 1", "te \
band 2", "te band 3", "te band 4", "te band 5", "te band 6", "te band \
7", "te band 8", "tefreqs:", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.561229, 0.793929, \
0.794659, 1.03341, 1.03342, 1.11597, 1.11681, "tefreqs:", 2, 0, 0.1, \
0, 0.11547, 0.101865, 0.559805, 0.79146, 0.793258, 0.992126, 1.02845, \
1.09799, 1.1151,
```

Apologies for the formatting of the list, I'm sure there's a nicer way to show it.

I'm guessing this might involve the Take command in some way - I'd like to extract the 7th-14th values, then the 21-28th values etc. I wanted to try using Take to say take eight values starting on the 7th element, then leave six, then take the next eight, but in the documentation I can't see that Mathematica allows extraction of a range.

Comment: Does this come from importing a file? I suspect `Import[]` with the appropriate settings would be a much cleaner job than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @J.M I've had trouble with that. If I import as data then yes I can extract the columns I'd like, but Mathematica imports everything as strings and the ToExpression command tells me the syntax is invalid so I can't then convert it to numbers. Importing as CSV means Mathematica recognises them as numbers.

Comment: Would you mind posting the file you have, on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) perhaps?

Comment: @J.M. Never used pastebin before, but does this link work? https://pastebin.com/SybuQE6G

Comment: This works: `Drop[Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SybuQE6G", "CSV", "HeaderLines" -> 1], None, 7]`. In your case, replace the URL with the location of your file.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, that works well.

Comment: In the future, you might want to give some context on any issue you encounter, so that people are not pursuing [XY problems](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Do you  require as output the list `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 201}` or `{"te band 1", "te band 2", "te band 3", "te band 4", "te band 5", "te band 6", "te band 7", "te band 8", "te band 45", "te band 201"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try with this.

I have edited your text, to check whether it works with numbers having more than one digit:

```
text = {"tefreqs:", "k index", "k1", "k2", "k3", "kmag/2pi", 
"te band 1", "te band 2", "te band 3", "te band 4", "te band 5", 
"te band 6", "te band 7", "te band 8", "te band 45", "te band 201", 
"tefreqs:", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.561229, 0.793929, 0.794659, 1.03341,
1.03342, 1.11597, 1.11681, "tefreqs:", 2, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.11547, 
0.101865, 0.559805, 0.79146, 0.793258, 0.992126, 1.02845, 1.09799, 
1.1151};

str = Flatten@(If[! NumericQ[#],If[StringMatchQ[#, "te band" ~~ __], {#}, Nothing], Nothing] & /@ text);

ToExpression@StringJoin[#] & /@ Map[If[DigitQ[#], #, Nothing] &, (Characters[#] & /@ str), {2}]

(* Out[143]:= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 45, 201} *)
```